# Question about sklearn (hyperparameter optimization)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was learning the random forest model and gradient boosting model and I wrote the following code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
rforest = RandomForestRegressor()
search_space = {'n_estimators':[100, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1250, 1500], 'min_samples_leaf':[1,5,10,20,25,30,40,50],'max_features': np.arange(1,train_x.shape[1]),}

rforest_search = RandomizedSearchCV(rforest, search_space, cv = 5, n_iter=20, return_train_score=False, n_jobs=-1, random_state=20)
rforest_search.fit(train_x,train_y)

print('Best parameters for random forest:', rforest_search.best_params_, '\n')
```

But an error occurred, this error did not occur when I was fitting the decision tree model. The error is:
**UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 18-20: ordinal not in range(128)**

I tried to use version 0.23.2 and 0.22.1 of sklearn, but the problem is still there. I want to know why this will occur and how to solve it.

The code I used for the decision tree model is:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
d_tree = DecisionTreeRegressor()

tuning_parameters = {'min_samples_leaf':[1,5,10,20,25,30],'max_depth':np.arange(1,50),}

dt_estimation = RandomizedSearchCV(d_tree, tuning_parameters, n_iter=20, cv=5, return_train_score=False)

#Since Decisiont Tree model is not sensitive to distribution and scaling, original data is used
dt_estimation.fit(train_x,train_y)
print("best_parms:{0}\nbest_score:{1}".format(dt_estimation.best_params_, dt_estimation.best_score_))
```

The whole error message is presented below:

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

D:\python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    667                                     verbose=self.verbose)
    668         results = {}
--> 669         with parallel:
    670             all_candidate_params = []
    671             all_out = []

D:\python\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __enter__(self)
    709     def __enter__(self):
    710         self._managed_backend = True
--> 711         self._initialize_backend()
    712         return self
    713 

D:\python\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in _initialize_backend(self)
    719         """Build a process or thread pool and return the number of workers"""
    720         try:
--> 721             n_jobs = self._backend.configure(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, parallel=self,
    722                                              **self._backend_args)
    723             if self.timeout is not None and not self._backend.supports_timeout:

D:\python\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in configure(self, n_jobs, parallel, prefer, require, idle_worker_timeout, **memmappingexecutor_args)
    492                 SequentialBackend(nesting_level=self.nesting_level))
    493 
--> 494         self._workers = get_memmapping_executor(
    495             n_jobs, timeout=idle_worker_timeout,
    496             env=self._prepare_worker_env(n_jobs=n_jobs),

D:\python\lib\site-packages\joblib\executor.py in get_memmapping_executor(n_jobs, **kwargs)
     18 
     19 def get_memmapping_executor(n_jobs, **kwargs):
---> 20     return MemmappingExecutor.get_memmapping_executor(n_jobs, **kwargs)
     21 
     22 

D:\python\lib\site-packages\joblib\executor.py in get_memmapping_executor(cls, n_jobs, timeout, initializer, initargs, env, temp_folder, context_id, **backend_args)
     40         _executor_args = executor_args
     41 
---> 42         manager = TemporaryResourcesManager(temp_folder)
     43 
     44         # reducers access the temporary folder in which to store temporary

D:\python\lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py in __init__(self, temp_folder_root, context_id)
    529             # exposes exposes too many low-level details.
    530             context_id = uuid4().hex
--> 531         self.set_current_context(context_id)
    532 
    533     def set_current_context(self, context_id):

D:\python\lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py in set_current_context(self, context_id)
    533     def set_current_context(self, context_id):
    534         self._current_context_id = context_id
--> 535         self.register_new_context(context_id)
    536 
    537     def register_new_context(self, context_id):

D:\python\lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py in register_new_context(self, context_id)
    558                 new_folder_name, self._temp_folder_root
    559             )
--> 560             self.register_folder_finalizer(new_folder_path, context_id)
    561             self._cached_temp_folders[context_id] = new_folder_path
    562 

D:\python\lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py in register_folder_finalizer(self, pool_subfolder, context_id)
    588         # semaphores and pipes
    589         pool_module_name = whichmodule(delete_folder, 'delete_folder')
--> 590         resource_tracker.register(pool_subfolder, "folder")
    591 
    592         def _cleanup():

D:\python\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\resource_tracker.py in register(self, name, rtype)
    189         '''Register a named resource, and increment its refcount.'''
    190         self.ensure_running()
--> 191         self._send('REGISTER', name, rtype)
    192 
    193     def unregister(self, name, rtype):

D:\python\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\resource_tracker.py in _send(self, cmd, name, rtype)
    202 
    203     def _send(self, cmd, name, rtype):
--> 204         msg = '{0}:{1}:{2}\n'.format(cmd, name, rtype).encode('ascii')
    205         if len(name) > 512:
    206             # posix guarantees that writes to a pipe of less than PIPE_BUF

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 18-20: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please add the full error message (including traceback, if possible)?

Comment: I have added the full error message. Thank you.